# What is the best way to Parse a PHP Array into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I currently have a PHP file that accesses my MySQL database and pulls out the Names and Scores for each player and stores them in an array.

```
 //This query grabs the top 10 scores, sorting by score and timestamp.
$query = "SELECT * FROM Score ORDER by score DESC, ts ASC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

//We find our number of rows
$result_length = mysql_num_rows($result); 

//And now iterate through our results
for($i = 0; $i < $result_length; $i++)
{
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     echo $row['name'] . "\t" . $row['score'] . "\n"; // And output them
}
```

What is the best way for me to get both the name and the score from the PHP File and store them in a Javascript Array?

Comment: What's the output of `$row` ?

Comment: As stated below, use an array to return the elements.  Have a $results = array();  and then in your for loop append to it with array_push($results, array("name" => $row["name"], "score" => $row["score"])); and at the end return it with json_encode($results);  When you get the response on the front end, you can take the response data and JSON.parse() it to turn it into a variable that you can access as parsedVariable[0].name, parsedVariable[0].score, etc.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: I added the following function to my Javascript Code:
`//Leaderboard $.get( "HighScores/TopScores.php", function(data) { var results = JSON.parse(data); console.log(2); results.forEach(function(result){ console.log( result.name +" - "+ result.score ); console.log(1) }); }, "json" );`
 But my Game doesn't seem to print anything out to the Console, not Name, Scores, "1" or "2"?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store them is store them in json. Use following function

```
json_encode(arrayname);
```

and in html use

```
$.parsejson(responsevariable);
```

to get original value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give json_encoded array to javascript variable (json_encode()), and use javascript json decoding functionality, so you will get what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a result variable

```
$results = array();
```

Store your results in it in your loop

```
array_push($results, array("name" => $row["name"], "score" => $row["score"]));
```

At the end return it with

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

When you get the response on the front end, you can take the response data and JSON.parse() it to turn it into a variable that you can access

```
var results = JSON.parse(data);

results.forEach(function(result){
    console.log( result.name +" - "+ result.score );
});
```

Comment: I added the following function to my Javascript Code:
`//Leaderboard
            $.get( "HighScores/TopScores.php", function(data) {
                var results = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(2);

                results.forEach(function(result){
                    console.log( result.name +" - "+ result.score );
                    console.log(1)
                });
            }, "json" );`

But my Game doesn't seem to print anything out to the Console, not Name, Scores, "1" or "2"?

Comment: Try doing a console.log(data) to see what it is coming back as.

Comment: I couldn't get the Console to log anything using the $.get function, so I changed it to:
`$.ajax({
                url: 'HighScores/TopScores.php',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    results = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    LoadedName = results[0].name;
                    LoadedScore = results[0].score;
                }
            });`
Which outputs:
`[{"name":"Conor","score":"100"},{"name":"Mark","score":"100"}]`

Comment: So that seems to be correct! However now if i use:
` results = JSON.parse(data);`
The Chrome console gives me the following error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
On Line 1 of my HTML page (Which just loads the Javascript files)

Comment: It's OK, I managed to fix it! The PHP file was also sending back an error warning me that mysql_connect was deprecated, so once I suppressed the warning then my code worked fine!